# GitLab - LDAP Authentication Issue

Tags: gitlab, ldap, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I am sorry if this issue has already been resolved, but I could not find any related answers.

I am trying to set up a self-hosted gitlab instance through docker-compose, which I wish to connect to an LDAP server.

(I have connected other applications to the same LDAP server in the past without issues, and also the account I am trying to login to is that of a valid user.)

However, no matter what I've tried I keep receiving this error upon login: `Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid filter syntax."`.

My current docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:14.8.6-ee.0'
    restart: on-failure
    hostname: 'host.namespace.com'
    container_name: gitlab-ee
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://host.namespace.com'
        gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
        gitlab_rails['ldap_host'] = 'ldap://something.something.com'
        gitlab_rails['ldap_port'] = 389
        gitlab_rails['ldap_base'] = 'ou=people,dc=namespace,dc=com'
        gitlab_rails['ldap_uid'] = 'uid'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

As you can see, in my current configuration I did not set `ldap_user_filter` at all, since it is not listed as required: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/#basic-configuration-settings.

However, I have also tried setting `gitlab_rails['ldap_user_filter'] = ''` or `gitlab_rails['ldap_user_filter'] = '(&(objectClass=zimbraAccount)(uid={login}))'` without any luck. Setting `gitlab_rails['bind_dn']` and other attributes did not help as well. I keep receiving the same "Invalid filter syntax." error over and over again.

Could you please point me to the right direction?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

`gitlab_rails['ldap_host'] = 'ldap://something.something.com'`

changed to:

`gitlab_rails['ldap_host'] = 'something.something.com'`